# Error Could not DER encode parameters: No OID for this transformation while connecting PayPal gateway

Tags: java, paypal, coldfusion, windows-server-2012, coldfusion-10

I am getting following error while connecting to PayPal gateway using CFHTTP :

> *Error : I/O Exception: com.rsa.crypto.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: Could not DER
>   encode parameters: No OID for this transformation*

My test code is :

```
<cfhttp url="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" 
        METHOD="get" 
        RESOLVEURL="false" 
        result="MyResult2">
</cfhttp>
<cfdump  label="Paypal_Production" var="#MyResult2#">
```

I have added PayPal's certificate to the java keystore by using keytool. I also tried the CertMan extension in ColdFusion. Anyone else encountered this issue before ?

- ColdFusion version : 10
- Java version : jre1.8.0_45

Comment: It looks like you need to pass some variables over. This does not look like it would do much of anything

Comment: This is just a test code to do a connectivity test to PayPal gateway.

Comment: Do you have a link to any documentation for this type of test?